# Tomcat cannot find servlets and JSP files when deployed on a different machine

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-lightsail

I have tested Apache Tomcat 9.0.14 on my local machine with both servlet classes and html/jsp files and it has no problem finding any of them. 
However, I now tried to deploy the same on a Amazon Lightsail instance by copying the complete Tomcat folder there and now it is only showing `404 not found` error message for everything.
Using bin/startup.sh clearly shows that the `CATALINA_HOME` variable is set to the correct directory.
I have no clue as to how do I reconfigure Tomcat (if required) so that it can find the servlet classes.
Note that I am trying to get classes in the webapps/ROOT folder.

Logs from "catalina.out" :

```
    28-Feb-2019 05:29:10.639 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.14
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 6 2018 21:13:53 UTC
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.14.0
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.15.0-1032-aws
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_201-b09
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/conf/logging.properties
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/temp
28-Feb-2019 05:29:11.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
28-Feb-2019 05:29:22.458 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Feb-2019 05:29:24.683 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Feb-2019 05:29:24.764 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [41,686] milliseconds
28-Feb-2019 05:29:26.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
28-Feb-2019 05:29:26.657 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
28-Feb-2019 05:29:26.905 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/webapps/ROOT]
28-Feb-2019 05:29:50.565 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/webapps/ROOT]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1868)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:637)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[13.232.118.245].StandardContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5041)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 42 more

28-Feb-2019 05:29:50.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [23,745] ms
28-Feb-2019 05:29:50.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/webapps/api-sample]
28-Feb-2019 05:29:57.234 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/webapps/api-sample]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1868)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:637)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[13.232.118.245].StandardContext[/api-sample]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5041)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 42 more

28-Feb-2019 05:29:57.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/webapps/api-sample] has finished in [6,745] ms
28-Feb-2019 05:29:57.397 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener.findDefaultHost Unknown default host [localhost] for service [StandardService[Catalina]]. Tomcat will not be able process HTTP/1.0 requests that do not specify a host name.
28-Feb-2019 05:29:57.398 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener.findDefaultHost Unknown default host [localhost] for service [StandardService[Catalina]]. Tomcat will not be able process HTTP/1.0 requests that do not specify a host name.
28-Feb-2019 05:29:57.398 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Feb-2019 05:29:58.384 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Feb-2019 05:29:58.386 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [33,621] milliseconds
28-Feb-2019 05:30:11.336 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
28-Feb-2019 05:30:11.418 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Feb-2019 05:30:11.582 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Feb-2019 05:30:11.829 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
28-Feb-2019 05:30:11.830 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener.findDefaultHost Unknown default host [localhost] for service [StandardService[Catalina]]. Tomcat will not be able process HTTP/1.0 requests that do not specify a host name.
28-Feb-2019 05:30:11.831 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Feb-2019 05:30:11.997 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Feb-2019 05:30:11.999 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Feb-2019 05:30:12.240 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: Please add Tomcat logs to the question

Comment: Added the logs from catalina.out after deleting all logs once, then restarting server

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
The issue was that I was putting all JAR files used in some classes in the Tomcat's shared "lib" folder.
Putting these only in the individual webapp's lib folder solved these problems.
Further explanation on `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;` would be appreciated.